# Container that grows with the text

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

If I have a div (button) with an icon inside and label next to it, and label is hidden unless mouse is hovered.

```
________
|      |
| :-)  |
|______|

_____________________
|                    |
| :-)  Hello World!  |
|____________________|
```

That's not so difficult to create, until you decide to add a transition effect.

What happens in my case - it immediately expands the container and then slowly unwraps the label. And I want them to expand together. How do I do that?

Can anybody show me an example.

I've tried playing around with `ng-hide, ng-hide-remove` classes, tried using flex-box, adding, removing custom classes - still can't figure out the elegant way of doing that.

Comment: `ng-hide` works with `display` property. you cannot make appearing animation with that.

Comment: aye... now, tell me something I don't know :)

Comment: write a custom directive that sets the height and width.  The reason why it doesn't work with display is because theres no scale with display, it's either on, off or on with properties like block/inline.  You can use either opacity or width/height depending on how you want the animation to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured a way to make it work using both `width` and `transform:scale()`

Comment: share the solution! interesting to see also!